# How do you name your "reference" implementations of an interface?

Tags: oop, interface

My question is rather simple and the title states it perfectly: How do you name your "reference" or "basic" implementations of an interface? I saw some naming conventions:

- FooBarImpl
- DefaultFooBar
- BasicFooBar

What do you use? What are the pros and cons? And where do you put those "reference" implementations? Currently i create an .impl package where the implementations go. More complex implementations which may contain multiple classes go into a .impl.complex package, where "complex" is a short name describing the implementation.

Thank you,
Malax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if your question reflects the customs of a particular language. I write in C#, and I typically don't have "default" implementation. I have an interface, say IDistance, and each implementation has a name that describes its actual purpose / how it is specific, say, EuclidianDistance, ManhattanDistance... In my opinion, "default" is not a property of the implementation itself, but of its context: the application could have a service/method called "GetDefaultDistance", which would be configured to return one of the distance implementations.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, (*whenever suitable*) I typically use a nested class called RefImpl.  This way for a given interface `InterfaceXYZ`, the reference implementation is always `InterfaceXYZ.RefImpl` and there is no need to fumble around making up effectively redundant names.

```
public interface InterfaceXYZ {

   // interface methods ...

   public static class RefImpl implements InterfaceXYZ {
        // interface method impls.
   }
}
```

And then have a uniform usage pattern:

```
// some where else
public void foo () {

    InterfaceXYZ  anXYZ = new InterfaceXYZ.RefImpl();

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I [asked a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945204/is-there-a-recognized-pattern-for-useless-objects-that-implement-an-interface) about a "null" implementation and it was identified as the null object pattern - an implementation of an interface that does nothing meaningful. Like Mathias, I'm not too sure what would be considered a "default" implementation that didn't have some kind of name specific to its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If the interface is a RazmaFrazzer, I'd call the implementation a DefaultRazmaFrazzer.

If you've already got several implementations and you've marked one of them out as a "default" look at all the implementations and **look at the differences between them and come up with an adjective that describes the distinguishing feature** of the default implementation e.g. SimpleRazmaFrazzer, or if it's a converter, you might have PassThroughDefaultRazmaFrazzer - so you're looking for whatever makes the implementation distinctive.

Answer (score 0):

The exact convention doesn't metter - be it `IService` + `Service` or `Service` + `ServiceImpl`. The point is to *be consistent throughout the whole project*.